# Twitter API 404 error with python twitter module

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to get the list of friends of a user using the Python twitter module. For some reason I keep getting 404 errors. I bet I am missing something very basic. Any ideas?

Thanks!

PS: all OAuth parameters replaced with XXXX.

```
import twitter

CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'XXXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'XXXX'

auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                           CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)

print twitter_api.GetFriends(user='twitter')
```

Then I get the following error:

```
TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 404 for URL: 1.1/GetFriends.json using parameters: (oauth_consumer_key=XXXX&oauth_nonce=XXXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1388098945&oauth_token=XXXX&oauth_version=1.0&user=twitter&oauth_signature=XXXX)
details: {"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

Comment: Gnerally users in Twitter API's are numerical, not string users, twitter works that way. Try this id `411396541` which is @HackRead

Comment: @PepperoniPizza well, that didn't work, I still get the 404 error. As far as I see if I send the request as `twitter_api.GetFriends()` without the user parameter, it should return my own follower list, however, I keep getting the 404 :)

Comment: You might have the Oauth wrong, `api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                      consumer_secret='consumer_secret',
                      access_token_key='access_token',
                      access_token_secret='access_token_secret')`

Comment: Is this for a specific user or multiple users?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python-twitter by DeWitt Clinton, then as PepperoniPizza mentioned, you have an error in your OAuth statement. Your code should be changed as follows:

```
auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                       CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
```

Should become

```
auth = twitter.Api(consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY, consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET, access_token_key=OAUTH_TOKEN, access_token_secret=OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

See here, under section "Using":

https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

However, looking at your code, your work doesn't seem to match how that library opens a connection to twitter. Which library are you using? It almost looks like you're using Mike Verdone's Python Twitter Tools.